# Google script using 'MailApp.sendEmail' truncating email addresses taken from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Forgive me as it is my first ever query on stackoverflow and I'm more of an Admin then any sort of developer.  I've been looking to use a sample script provided by Google in their '[Transformation Gallery](https://transformationgallery.withgoogle.com/card/5762637883244544?lang=en)'.
It is straight forward enough to get up and running but I'm finding that it truncates one of the email address values that it grabs from the spreadsheet.

For example.   A requestor asks for a specific day off, fills out the form and fires off the request to an approver.   The approver mail bounces as the format we use for our email naming convention is first_lastname@xxxx.com.

So what ends up happening is it truncates to just lastname@xxxx.com and bounces.  However when a manager approves the request the return email going to the requestor goes fine, so the one MailApp.sendEmail routine works fine, but one does not.

From what I can tell this function manages the value from the Managers Email fields:

```
 d.manager_email = manager_email

message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL, d);
subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);

MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });

setRowData(_sheet, d);
```

And the working one that send a reply back to the requestor based on the approval appears to be this:

```
var approveByKey = function(k, user) {
var d = _getDataByKey(k);
d.state = APPROVED_STATE;
d.actor = user;

var message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_APPROVAL_EMAIL, d);
var subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_APPROVAL_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
MailApp.sendEmail(d.emailAddress,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });

if(SETTINGS.SEND_APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL == 1) {
  var message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL, d);
  var subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
  MailApp.sendEmail(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_TO, subject, "",{ htmlBody: message });
}
```

I'm not quite sure why the first example is truncating the value taken from the 'manager_email'.   Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0):

From the above example, the difference is `d.emailAddress` & `d.manager_email` & `SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_TO` if `d.emailAddress` & `SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_TO` are working, then it should work if changed to one of those.

```
// Assuming this variable assignment is somewhere in the method of the top example
var d = _getDataByKey(k);

// Change the `manager_email` to d.emailAddress or to SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_TO
MailApp.sendEmail(d.emailAddress, subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });
```

Other then that, if that is not the problem, more code would be needed as somewhere along the line the email is altered before the parts of the code that has been posted. Wherever `SETTINGS` or `d` has been set

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction.  In another part of the google apps provided script they apply some formatting to var 'manager_email'.  I removed it and it is now working as expected.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this example to provide 80% of the functionality of the application I am working on.

The Code that changes the email address is this line;

```
manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME].match(EMAIL_REGEX);
```

I had to change this to:  `manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME] ;`  I could not get the "`.match(var EMAIL_REGEX = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z+0-9\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+", 'i');` "
to play nice with my Email Addresses.